# Can I see how long a JavaScript function takes to execute in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, performance, debugging, firebug

Is there a way to get a timeline for "normal" JavaScript functions like there is for Ajax, images, etc. in Firebug?

[image: Timeline for Ajax]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no timeline for functions in Firebug, but you can use it's [Profiler](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Profiler) feature inside the [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel) to get a numerical output of the JavaScript timings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the profile tab on chrome debugger for start recording a JavaScript CPU profile like

[image]

For more information about [**PROFILE**](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a date object at start and end of the method and do some thing like

endDate - startDate and print this to the console.

This is only for performance checking and later you can remove the start date and end date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this seems to be a rather inconvenient solution.